# How can i pass parameters in a migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I wish to pass parameters within an initial migration and run the migration runtime.
(Via c# code not with PM commands)

In the example below i am trying so via the constructor (parameter name tableName)

```
public interface IDbContextSchema
{
    string TableName { get; set; }
}

public partial class v1 : Migration, IDbContextSchema
{
    public string TableName { get; set;}

    public v1(string tableName)
    {
        TableName = tableName;
    }

    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: TableName,
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                CustomerName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey($"PK_WU_{TableName}", x => x.Id);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: TableName);
    }
}
```

It seems that the approach above will do the trick.
But how am i supposed to run the migration runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can start migration manually (from C# code) with `context.Database.Migrate()` command.

Check [the code of migrate function](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/fb7be71c673f70deed4dbff29ed27afc31a8c45e/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs#L39) and you'll see that it uses a `[IMigrator][2]` that generates code.

There you can find how to get control on migration assembly `((IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>)context.Database).Instance.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>()`  (Please double check if it returns a value)

`IMigrationsAssembly` has function `CreateMigration` which takes `[TypeInfo][2]` parameter.

I guess, would be the way to generate classes dynamically inherited from your base migration class, but with the overriden constructor parameter, defining table name